# Why is FormControl not marked dirty in Angular 10 unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, angular-reactive-forms, angular10

The following test passes with Angular 9, but fails with Angular 10. Why?

upgrade-test.component.html:

```html
<input [formControl]="formControl" />
```

upgrade-test.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-upgrade-test',
  templateUrl: './upgrade-test.component.html'
})
export class UpgradeTestComponent {
  formControl: FormControl = new FormControl(0);
}
```

upgrade-test.component.spec.ts:

```js
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { UpgradeTestComponent } from './upgrade-test.component';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

describe('Test', () => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [UpgradeTestComponent],
    imports: [ReactiveFormsModule],
  });

  it('should pass', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UpgradeTestComponent);
    const component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.formControl.dirty).toBeFalsy();

    component.formControl.patchValue(1);
    const inputElem: HTMLInputElement = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('input');
    inputElem.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.formControl.dirty).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Test result:

```
  Test
    ✗ should pass
        Expected false to be truthy.
            at UserContext. (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/src/app/components/upgrade-test/upgrade-test.component.spec.ts:21:41)
            at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:364:1)
            at ProxyZoneSpec.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:292:1)
            at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:363:1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the `patchValue()` or `setValue()` methods do not change the `dirty` status of the control or the form.

> A control is dirty if the user has changed the value in the UI.

https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#dirty

Comment: This didn't change between Angular 9 and 10, at least in the docs. Regardless, there has to be some way to programmatically simulate changing the value in the UI. When the value is changed in the UI, typically that generates a "change" event, so dispatching a change event on the input in code should have the same effect. If Angular changed the event that causes the control to become dirty from "change" to something else, then what is it?

Comment: Indeed, nothing has changed regarding this aspect between Angular 9 and 10, so I'm surprised it was working before. I would suggest to try either firing the `blur` instead of the `change` event, or simulating typing in the field using your testing frawework, instead of using `patchValue`.